# What is the random variable $X_T$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am a beginner to Markov chains, while learning about stopping time and the Strong Markov Property, I saw something like $\{ X_{T} = i \}$, where $X: \Omega \to I$ , I being a countable space where the corresponding Sigma field of $\Omega$ is $\mathcal{F}$, and $P(I)$ for I. T also a random variable: $T:\Omega \to \{ 0,1,2, \dots \} \cup \{ \infty \}$. As in a typical Markov chain, $X_{i}$ just means the i-th random variable.

Intuitively, it makes sense that $X_{T}$ is just another random variable, and $\{{X_{T} = i} \}$ is an event, but I don't understand what it is logically.

> Specifically, why $\mathbb{P}(\{ X_{T} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \}) = \mathbb{P}(\{ X_{j} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \})$? How can one just make a substitution like this?

Comment: I have no background whatsoever in measure theory nor stochastic processes... but isn't $\mathbb{P}(\{ X_{T} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \}) = \mathbb{P}(\{ X_{j} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \})$ logically true? I mean $(\{ X_{T} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \})=(\{ X_{j} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \})$, we just replaced $X_T$ with $X_j$ since $T=j$. Seems legit to my brain :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_T$ means, take the value of random variable $T$, use that as the index in the sequence $X_j$, and take the value of the random variable $X_j$ with that index. Thus
$\{ X_T = i\}$ is the event that $X_j = i$ where $j$ is the value of the random variable $T$. You could write it as
$$ \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty \{X_j = i,\; T = j\}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before I accept this, just to make sure, the substitution rule holds because $\{T = j, T = i\}$ is the empty set right? Also, I have not learned this yet, but if T is something that maps to the Reals, the uncountable union of events doesn't has to be an event, so how is it $X_T$ defined in this case?

Comment: $\{T=j, \; T=i\}$ means $T=j$ and $T=i$.  That's empty if $i \ne j$, but I don't see what that has to do with this question.  If $T$ can have arbitrary real values, $X_T$ doesn't make sense when $X_i$ is a sequence of random variables.  You'd need to be able to make sense of $X_t$ for an arbitrary real $t$.

Comment: Thank you. I mean if we write $\{ X_{T} = i \}$it as the union, and intersect that union it with $\{ T = j \}$, all terms would disappear besides $(\{ X_{j} = i \} \cap \{ T = j \})$